# You "show" someone a picture. You "---" someone a song?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, verbs, translation

In [Maltese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltese_language), we have a verb meaning "to show" corresponding to "to see/to look", and we have a different verb corresponding to "to hear/to listen":

> inti **tara** stampa (you look at a picture.) ---- jiena **nurilek** stampa (I show you a picture)
>
> inti **tisma'** diska (you listen to a song.) ----- jiena **nsemmagħlek** diska (I 'show' you a song)

In English, do you "show someone a song" (sounds weird to me) or is there a verb that corresponds more directly to the Maltese *insemmgħek*?

Comment: This is a tricky one. In the music business you'd say "I'll *let you hear* this new track..."  Note that you could "show" a song, meaning, the sheet music. And note that indeed you COULD say "here, I'll show you how the song goes..." and then play it on piano.

Comment: It occurs to me the "actual answer" here in real life, when "play" does not really work, is probably "let them listen to ...".  So you might say "Where's my sister, I must let her listen to this song..."

Comment: Or possibly, *make* her or *have* her, listen to a song.

Comment: Another possibility is to *share* a song with someone.

Comment: I think "showing someone a song" can work but might feel slightly informal: "Jack showed me this amazing song last night." According to fredsbends' answer this usage is likely only for introducing someone to a song.

Comment: 'insemm' translates to 'mention'. What does 'għek' mean?

Comment: 'għalik' means 'for you'. Then, insemmgħek translates into "mention for you"

Comment: I added a comment about this a few days ago, and somebody removed it without a reason.  Generally the word "show" works just fine, although "play" is slightly fancier and more cultured.  "Show" also has a slightly different meaning, a meaning which is closer to that of "to present" than literally "to play".  A common example might be, "Hey, man, let me show you this song I've been working on."  This would generally involve playing the song, although it could, for instance, involve showing a set of sheet music instead.

Comment: You can make someone listen a song

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I don't know anything about Maltese grammar, but I want to guess that **nurik** and **nsemmgħek** mean, respectively 'cause to look' and 'cause to listen'. Some languages have standard ways of converting one verb to a causative verb (one that means 'to cause to do'). As an example, in Classical Nahuatl the suffix `-ti` turns any verb into a causative verb. So the word **cueponi** could mean *bloom (flowers)*, then **cueponaltia** *to cause flowers to bloom*.

In English there is no automatic way to make a verb into a causative verb. If you have a pair like **die** and **kill** (cause to die), then that is just your good luck that you have a causative verb corresponding to **die** (Classical Nahuatl has **miqui** *die* and **mictia** *kill*, using the same `-ti` suffix).

So there is no single word in English that means *cause to listen*. If you say *Thomas played Molly a song* that means that Thomas played a song for Molly's benefit. Any English transitive verb can take a benefactive reading using this construction (think of the Bob Dylan song that goes *God said to Abraham, kill me a son*). **Play** is probably the best word you could use, but it doesn't mean *cause to listen*.

Comment: You are correct about *nurik* and *insemmgħek* meaning "(I) cause (you) to see/look" and "(I) cause (you) to hear/listen".

Comment: To "tell" someone something is to cause him to listen.  But you don't really "tell" a song.  You can tell someone a story though.

Answer (score 65):

In English, we would usually use the word *play*. That covers both the act of performing the song on an instrument (perhaps while singing, if the instrument permits) *and* the act of playing a recording of the song. If you give an *a cappella* rendition, live, you would use the word *sing*.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but it doesn't precisely capture the meaning of the Maltese verb. A very rare case of Maltese being richer than English I suppose :)

Comment: This would be the answer chosen by the lyrics to Sweet Transvestite: "So let me **show you around**, maybe **play you a sound**, you look like you're both pretty groovy..."

Answer (score 9):

Per @bye's answer, in the case of a song, you'd probably *play* or *sing* it to someone else (depending on how you cause the sound to be made). But if you wanted the band at your private party to play some particular song that you can't think of the name of, the bandleader might say:-

> *"You [**hum it**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you%20hum%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22you%20hum%20it%20and%22&tbm=bks) and we'll play it"* (just give us idea of what it sounds like; we'll probably recognise it)

---

More generic verbs (which could also be used of a *taste* or *smell* as well as a *sight* or *sound*) are:-

> [**present**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/present) *- to offer for observation, examination, or consideration; show or display*
>    [**demonstrate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demonstrate) *- to give a demonstration*

Comment: present and demonstrate are excellent realisations.

Answer (score 6):

*Play* is good if you want something specifically for sound, but I would generally use *show* here. It refers to introducing or presenting new information in a variety of contexts, not strictly related to sight. For example, “He showed me a great new sandwich shop”. I find it no different than saying “I see” to metaphorically mean “I understand”.

Answer (score 4):

In Russian, we say "дать послушать" which means something like *give to listen* or *give a listen* (according to Google translate), like if you have some recording (MP3, CD etc) and you give that recording to someone. In English, it's similar. You could say to your friend "give a listen to this song" or "give this song a listen".

Answer (score 3):

As was suggested, you could use the word ***play***. But the word ***show*** is also acceptable. The word show does not exclusively mean ***cause to be seen***. Other meanings include:

> 3 :  to present as a public spectacle :  perform
>   6
>       a :  to point out :  direct attention to 
>       b :  conduct, usher 
>   7 :  accord, bestow 
>   [Source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show)

Definition six (a) is what you mean when you "show" someone a song, typically. You are probably going to pull it up on YouTube or something so they can hear it *for the first time*. The assumption under this scenario is that they have never heard the song before and *showing it to them* directs their attention to it. *Playing a song for someone* does not necessarily imply that.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to say "I'll load up that song for you", but that phrase tends to imply that the song is stored as a file on a computer, so it might not work if the recording is stored on a more old-fashioned medium.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a single-word English translation of the concept of "make someone listen to something."  However, if we stop focusing on the looking-*vs.*-listening distinction, we have terms like:

- **Share.**  For example, the Internet is full of buttons that let you *share* a link with your friends, meaning that you want someone else to have the same experience you had.
- **Introduce.** That is a form of sharing where you believe that someone does not yet know of something.
- **Recommend.** That is a form of sharing where you expect that someone will like the experience, because you know the other person's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest is "have you listen to," but it's only candid to say you've found an asymmetry in English, and native speakers will have slight awkwardness when ???ing someone a song. Possible ways this might be done:

- "I want to show you this song" somewhat acceptable still, possibly because it's understood there's no perfect way to say this
- "I want you to listen to this song" acceptable, but different color since it's not *me* doing something to/for *you* anymore.
- "I want to have you listen to this song" resolves above difficulty but is longer and more awkward that way. I think it's preferred.

Answer (score 0):

'**Make mention**' is a passable English phrase for "mention for you", insemmgħek. As pointed out, there's no one-English-word to translate this compound word into. When someone plays music for another, they are ***serenading*** them. However, this normally connotes a romantic, appropriate, and well received selection, unless said in jest.

Answer (score -3):

"I will sing you a song " seems good enough

Comment: Yes, but only if you sing it yourself.

Comment: Singing would only be a representation of the song unlike "showing" a picture. This would be akin to "describing" a picture.