# A photograph 'depicts' its object. Is there a comparable verb for audio recordings?

Tags: single-word-requests

A photograph 'depicts' its object. Is there a comparable word for audio recordings?

For example, "The recording [verbs] The Beatles playing *Been a Hard Day's Night*."

Comment: I realise it means something different, but in your example I'd use `contains`

Comment: A recording **records** their performance... at least according to the Department of Redundancy Department.

Comment: It seems like a complex comparison if we squarely consider what a photo does when it depicts. If it shows, then a recording would perhaps most comparably play. If it preserves, or holds, then perhaps we want contain. Why is depict used? That is, Why tell someone what a photo depicts? Usually to label or identify. Only contain or hold comes to mind again as comparable.

Comment: 'reproduces' may fit well.. perhaps it's just me, I would not mind using 'depicts'for music or pictures.

Comment: Your analogy between "photograph" and "recording" sounds incorrect.

Comment: related:[You “show” someone a picture. You “---” someone a song?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190677/you-show-someone-a-picture-you-someone-a-song)

Comment: If a "picture" "de*pict*s", does a "recording" "de*cord*"?

Comment: Given @Mari-LouA 's link. Perhaps, 'replays'? Just spitballing.

Comment: @Mustafa I wonder whether that's true. A depiction may abstractly represent something. But a recording - not so much.

Comment: Although @JimReynolds is right. I'm looking for something that does the work that 'contains' does in this context.'Replays' doesn't do that.

Comment: As an aside, the correct title of the Beatles song is "A Hard Days Night"

Comment: A picture and a recording are different things, in that a recording duplicates a performance, where a picture is a snapshot of a small part of the world. When you take a photo of the cat, you don't end up with a second cat.

Comment: @DaleM, the correct title has an apostrophe in "Day's." http://www.amazon.com/Hard-Days-Night-John-Lennon/dp/B0000542D2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The verb ***depict*** can be defined as *to represent, as a painting or picture does* (that's from OED's definition for OP's context).

There is no "medium-specific" verb for ***representing*** something in an auditory, olfactory, gustatory, or tactile medium (songs, perfumes, statues, etc.). Figurative use, such as [*the song depicts [whatever it's supposed to "reflect, invoke"*]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=firefox-a&hs=dyb&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&channel=sb&q=%22confects%20the%20bread%22&oq=%22confects%20the%20bread%22&gs_l=serp.3...649075.649075.0.649194.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..58.serp..1.0.0.EoCbyRXOQmI&gfe_rd=cr&ei=0uVkVK38HsnH8geSgYKwBA#rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&channel=sb&q=%22the%20song%20depicts%22) is perfectly common. Otherwise, you can just use ***to represent*** in all contexts for all mediums.

---

The more "literal" general-purpose verbs include *invoke, express, emulate, show, suggest*, etc. Alternatives which are more "figurative" include *reflect, capture, encapsulate*, etc.

Comment: While *depict* might be "medium-agnostic" (not to be confused with a small atheist), it seems increasingly difficult to use "depict" as one moves away from the visual media. "This painting depicts Jane Eyre." "This statuette depicts the Statue of Liberty." "This song ?depicts 'A Hard Day's Night.'" "This scratch 'n' sniff ?depicts Absolut Vodka." "This ratatouille ??depicts a dish from my childhood." (Incidentally, shouldn't the plural for *medium* be *media* at the end of your second paragraph?)

Comment: I think *This song ??? "A Hard Day's Night"* is a slightly different context. In practice it's just a song title, not really something that can be "represented" using words or pictures. Though as I said, "represent" seems to work in all contexts where it's meaningful to equate an artwork with an external referent. As for the plural of *medium*, I'm happy with my usage - [*In art, where medium refers to materials used to create a piece, both plurals are commonly used.*](http://grammarist.com/usage/media-mediums/) (But I fully expected someone to query it! :)

Answer (score 14):

**Capture** could cover both photographs and sound recordings.

Answer (score 4):

The recording **reproduces** The Beatles playing "A Hard Day's Night.", with a warmth and clarity that only Vinyl can deliver.

Answer (score 2):

Music may **evoke** something or may **reflect** something. Eg:

```
Music evokes so many feelings in us, memories, nostalgia, things that are connected to our past.
```

Comment: But that's not the same as a picture "depicting".

Answer (score 1):

If it is a digital representation, you could say

"This MP3

- ripped
- digitized
- encoded
- [discretized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization)

the Beatles rendition of *A Hard Day's Night*."

(These words may get to the partial representation with some loss of fidelity, but it must be of the original song and band.)

If it is a group other than the Beatles performing the song, you could say, "The recording **covers** The Beatles *A Hard Day's Night*." (This may get to aspect of the imitation or recasting of a song, and must be performed by a different band.)

And, for the record, I had no idea that Alvin and the Chipmunks [covered A Hard Day's Night](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cover_versions_of_Beatles_songs).

Answer (score 0):

"Depict" is for artistic representation, not recorded or mechanical representation. That is, a "painting depicts" and a "photograph records."

However, your question appears to be about the representative meaning of a picture vs. the representative meaning of a piece of music. This is also relates to how you experience a painting - you view it. With music, you listen to it.

"Depicts" is a description of what the object you are interacting with is "doing" (it is "representing" something).

A painting "depicts" a subject. A musician "plays" a score. A singer "sings" a song.

When a musician plays or singer sings, it is their artistic representation of that music.