# Verb to cause one to listen, as in "show" means to cause one to see

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

We may say, for example,

> May I **show** you my favorite painting by Monet?

> Tomorrow, I will **show** my grandmother my dance recital video recording.

where 'show' means to cause one to see something *visual*.

However, I can't think of an English verb to cause someone to hear or listen to something auditory, as in,

> May I **show** you my favorite composition by Debussy?

> Tomorrow, I will **show** my grandmother my clarinet recital audio recording.

The word 'show' in the above sentences seems to mean that I intend to present written sheet music or display a digital audio file on a screen.

But if I intend for one to *listen* to a piece of music (or anything auditory), is there a single verb which can replace the word **show** in the above sentences?

---

The most concise verb phrase I've thought of (aside from using 'listen' as a command, i.e., "Listen to this composition.") is:

> May I **have** you **listen to** my favorite composition by Debussy?

> Tomorrow, I will **have** my grandmother **listen to** my clarinet audio recording.

But I would prefer a single verb, if one exists.

Comment: That isn't quite what _show_ means. It can and often does refer to non-visual demonstrations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases where you're having the person listen to an audio recording or something musical, the verb ***play*** is appropriate.

For example,

> May I play you my favorite composition by Debussy?

would be fitting if you want to either play a recording of the piece, or if you're sitting at a piano and want to play it yourself. This phrasing works for any audio recording, since starting the playback of a recording is just "playing" it - you could "play someone a speech", "play someone a recording of birdsong", or "play someone the sound of a motorcycle", so long as they are all recorded sounds.

For things that are not recordings or musical, "play" doesn't fit. If you want to show off the sound of your new motorcycle in person, for example, you don't "play someone the sound of the motorcycle". In this case, *show* could be used for non-visual stimuli, as "show" most generally just means "display or allow to be perceived". One could show their anger through the tone of their voice or the words they choose, even if they are speaking over the telephone, so "show" does not strictly imply a visual phenomenon. So, you could say:

> I'd like to show you the sound of my new motorcycle.

although this does sound a little odd to me. Other phrasings with "show" sound a bit more natural, such as:

> Let me show you what my motorcycle sounds like at full throttle.

perhaps because it doesn't have the unusual phrasing of "showing a sound", but instead "shows what it sounds like". At any rate, you can't go wrong by rephrasing to use a more auditory-oriented verb, such as:

> I'd like you to hear my new motorcycle.

Comment: I will play my recording for my grandmother.

Comment: "I'd like to play you ..." or "I'd like you to hear ..." is probably the most natural phrasing. I have heard people use "serenade" (in verb form), but usually in an ironic or comical way.

Comment: "I'd like you to listen to..." is probably the closest to "I'd like to show you" in most cases. In particular we often say this to a technician or mechanic when a piece of equipment is making a strange noise as in "I'd like you to listen to my motorbike, there's an odd rattle when it gets up to 3000 revs."

Answer (score 0):

A verb very closely linked to *show*, but which works better than *show* for sounds in the example sentences, is [**demonstrate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demonstrate):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : to show clearly
>     // *demonstrate* a willingness to cooperate
>     // must *demonstrate* mastery of the subject matter in order to pass the class
>     // The police *demonstrated* calm restraint during the riot.
> **2 a** : to prove or make clear by reasoning or evidence
>        // crowded classrooms that *demonstrate* the need for more schools in the area
> **2 b** : to illustrate and explain especially with many examples
>        // *demonstrate* a procedure
> **3** : to show or prove the value or efficiency of to a prospective buyer
>     // *demonstrate* a new kitchen gadget

The example sentences in the question become the following:

- May I *demonstrate* my favourite composition by Debussy [to you]?
- Tomorrow, I will *demonstrate* my clarinet audio recording [to my grandmother].

In cases where *show* doesn't fit *demonstrate* does. In fact, it's intransitive use is often more natural than that of *show*.

---

Note that just as *show* is not limited only to vision, *demonstrate* is not limited only to sound.

Comment: To *demonstrate* something typically has an instructive, illustrative, or exemplary purpose, none of which apply here. One might demonstrate a Debussy composition in order to set an example of what it sounds like (for others to play), or to show contrasts among 19th century composers, but just playing a recording for someone because you like it isn't really a demonstration. The first definition "to show clearly" is normally showing the *existence* of something, rather than anything about whatever it is you're demonstrating - one does not need to demonstrate that Debussy exists.

Answer (score 0):

It may be instructive to read [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208020/a-photograph-depicts-its-object-is-there-a-comparable-verb-for-audio-recordin/208025#208025) and its answers.

> **A photograph 'depicts' its object. Is there a comparable verb for
> audio recordings?**