# Single word for "make someone cry"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a single word for "make someone cry"? I checked a translation dictionary, but it just referred me to the word "cry."

Comment: Did you check a translation dictionary?

Comment: "Hurting" someone comes close but I don't think English has a single verb that could replace it.

Comment: @Mitch Both of the Hindi words yield 'cry'

Comment: Why do you need a single word? Can you write an example sentence where the word would be used? As it stands, your question is off-topic.

Comment: There are so many diverse reasons that someone might be caused to cry it seems unreasonable to attempt to force the use of a single word.

Comment: English doesn't have a single word for this. Some agglutinative languages can have single words for these kind of concepts.

Comment: It depends on the type of "tears". Are they of sadness? Joy? Rage? You can *enrage* someone to the point of tears, but you can also do the same by telling a joke.

Comment: @TsSkTo: In some languages, it doesn't  depend on the context. You just use affixes to change the word from "to cry" to "to make someone cry". Also, in English, you can still use "made me cry" for all those emotions. You just have to include the context around it.

Comment: Similar question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190677/you-show-someone-a-picture-you-someone-a-song

Answer (score 0):

If the tears indicate sorrow, you can use the word ***sadden***:

> : to cause (someone) to be sad
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sadden)</sub>

There is also the phrasal verb ***tear up***:

> **2**. To cause to have tears well in the eyes: *By the movie's end, the whole audience was **teared up**.*
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tear+up)</sub>